# Strip trailing slashes from a string in Excel

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

There are multiple rows in excel. And here is the sample pattern:

```
/xxx/yyy/zzz////
/xxx/yyy/zzz//
/xxx/yyy/zzz//////
/xxx/yyy/zzz
```

When the slashes are removed the output will look as follows:

```
/xxx/yyy/zzz
/xxx/yyy/zzz
/xxx/yyy/zzz
/xxx/yyy/zzz
```

Please let me know the Excel formula to strip the slashes. The last sample pattern doesn't contain any slashes. Thanks!

I tried this formula, and it dosn`t work -

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="/",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))+1),A1)
```

Comment: Use `TEXTBEFORE()` that will be **succinct** the `3rd` approach i have shown in `Asnwers`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your pattern is truly representative, then

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("//",A1&"//")-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Great!, if the question is about removing trailing `//` this is on point!. For even number of trailing `//`like it seems to be in the question, this would work too: `=TEXTSPLIT(A1,"//",,1)`

Comment: @DavidLeal Although the sample data has an even number of trailing slashes, I don't see where that restriction is mentioned in the Title or the text of the question.

Comment: Yes, the question has just one sample data  (with an even number of trailing slash) the rest was left two our imagination, the OP  only indicates “strip the slashes”, :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
="/"&TEXTJOIN("/",,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/",,1))
```

---

**Edit:**

Using <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd> <kbd>TAKE( )</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",0,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),,4))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",0,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,"/"),4))
```

---

Or, if you like to Spill with DAF

[image]

---

• in cell `B1`

```
=MAP(A1:A4,LAMBDA(m,TEXTJOIN("/",0,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(m,,"/"),4))))
```

---

**Caveat:** I think adding a caveat makes sense for the second approaches. Because I have assumed anything before the `4th` occurrence of `/` needs to stay and rest is removed, if there is no `4th` one it should be as is.

---

This is my two cents, can't be better than this. Using <kbd>TEXTBEFORE( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1&"/","/",4)
```

---

Or, a spilled one:

[image]

---

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1:A4&"/","/",4)
```

---

Since I am not aware of your Excel Version, adding an alternate version, which works for Excel 2010+ onwards.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1&"/","/","@",4),
FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1&"/","/","@",4))-1)
```

---

Comment: Great solution Mayukh!, just one suggestion for `TEXTBEFORE` approach, I would use: `=TEXTBEFORE(A1,"/",4,,1)` or `=TEXTBEFORE(A1,"/",4,,,A1)` taking advantage of `TEXTBEFORE` additional input arguments.

Comment: Thank you, Mayukh - the textbefore and textsplit versions of the solution didn't work because I am not using Excel 365. The  last solution worked. Have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

Are you specifically asking for just the trailing forward slashes? If so, you may want to try:

[image]

Fomula in `B1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A6,LAMBDA(x,TEXTBEFORE(x,TEXTAFTER(x,TEXTSPLIT(x,"/",,1),-1),-1)))
```

Or, a little more strict (in case you have just forward slashes:

```
=MAP(A1:A7,LAMBDA(x,LEFT(x,@TOCOL(FIND(REPT("/",SEQUENCE(LEN(x),,LEN(x)-1,-1))&"@",x&"@")-1,3))))
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't have Textbefore function available with my version of Excel. The second solution gave me an error - that function isn't valid!

Comment: Great! I prefer the 1st one wrapped in an IFERROR to return blank if blank or only slashes. The 2nd one returns a single slash if only slashes and an error if blank but the idea behind it is gold.

Answer (score 2):

### Remove Trailing Occurrences of a Character

[image]

```
=LET(data,A2:A11,ch,"/",dch,"@",es,"",od,"",
    BYROW(data,LAMBDA(br,
        IF(LEN(br)=0,es,LET(
            rd,REDUCE(br,SEQUENCE(LEN(br)),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
                    ri,RIGHT(rr,1),
                IF(ri=dch,rr,IF(ri=ch,LEFT(rr,LEN(rr)-1),rr&dch))))),
            IF(LEN(rd)=0,od,LEFT(rd,LEN(rd)-1)))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for trying this solution - I am not familiar with using VB via Excel.

Answer (score 0):

"The last sample pattern doesn't contain any slashes."
Suppose the last cell is A4

```
=LEFT(A1;LEN($A$4))
```